# How to reverse sklearn.OneHotEncoder transform to recover original data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I encoded my categorical data using `sklearn.OneHotEncoder` and fed them to a random forest classifier. Everything seems to work and I got my predicted output back.

Is there a way to reverse the encoding and convert my output back to its original state?

Answer (score 26):

A good systematic way to figure this out is to start with some test data and work through the [`sklearn.OneHotEncoder`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L1655) source with it. If you don't much care about how it works and simply want a quick answer, skip to the bottom.

```
X = np.array([
    [3, 10, 15, 33, 54, 55, 78, 79, 80, 99],
    [5, 1, 3, 7, 8, 12, 15, 19, 20, 8]
]).T
```

## n_values_

[Lines 1763-1786](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L1763-L1786) determine the `n_values_` parameter. This will be determined automatically if you set `n_values='auto'` (the default). Alternatively you can specify a maximum value for all features (int) or a maximum value per feature (array). Let's assume that we're using the default. So the following lines execute:

```
n_samples, n_features = X.shape    # 10, 2
n_values = np.max(X, axis=0) + 1   # [100, 21]
self.n_values_ = n_values
```

## feature_indices_

Next the `feature_indices_` parameter is calculated.

```
n_values = np.hstack([[0], n_values])  # [0, 100, 21]
indices = np.cumsum(n_values)          # [0, 100, 121]
self.feature_indices_ = indices
```

So `feature_indices_` is merely the cumulative sum of `n_values_` with a 0 prepended.

## Sparse Matrix Construction

Next, a [`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) is constructed from the data. It is initialized from three arrays: the sparse data (all ones), the row indices, and the column indices.

```
column_indices = (X + indices[:-1]).ravel()
# array([  3, 105,  10, 101,  15, 103,  33, 107,  54, 108,  55, 112,  78, 115,  79, 119,  80, 120,  99, 108])

row_indices = np.repeat(np.arange(n_samples, dtype=np.int32), n_features)
# array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9], dtype=int32)

data = np.ones(n_samples * n_features)
# array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

out = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row_indices, column_indices)),
                        shape=(n_samples, indices[-1]),
                        dtype=self.dtype).tocsr()
# <10x121 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>' with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Note that the `coo_matrix` is immediately converted to a [`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/csr_matrix.html). The `coo_matrix` is used as an intermediate format because it "facilitates fast conversion among sparse formats."

## active_features_

Now, if `n_values='auto'`, the sparse csr matrix is compressed down to only the columns with active features. The sparse `csr_matrix` is returned if `sparse=True`, otherwise it is densified before returning.

```
if self.n_values == 'auto':
    mask = np.array(out.sum(axis=0)).ravel() != 0
    active_features = np.where(mask)[0]  # array([  3,  10,  15,  33,  54,  55,  78,  79,  80,  99, 101, 103, 105, 107, 108, 112, 115, 119, 120])
    out = out[:, active_features]  # <10x19 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>' with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
    self.active_features_ = active_features

return out if self.sparse else out.toarray()
```

## Decoding

Now let's work in reverse. We'd like to know how to recover `X` given the sparse matrix that is returned along with the `OneHotEncoder` features detailed above. Let's assume we actually ran the code above by instantiating a new `OneHotEncoder` and running `fit_transform` on our data `X`.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
ohc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()  # all default params
out = ohc.fit_transform(X)
```

The key insight to solving this problem is understanding the relationship between `active_features_` and `out.indices`. For a `csr_matrix`, the indices array contains the column numbers for each data point. However, these column numbers are not guaranteed to be sorted. To sort them, we can use the `sorted_indices` method.

```
out.indices  # array([12,  0, 10,  1, 11,  2, 13,  3, 14,  4, 15,  5, 16,  6, 17,  7, 18, 8, 14,  9], dtype=int32)
out = out.sorted_indices()
out.indices  # array([ 0, 12,  1, 10,  2, 11,  3, 13,  4, 14,  5, 15,  6, 16,  7, 17,  8, 18,  9, 14], dtype=int32)
```

We can see that before sorting, the indices are actually reversed along the rows. In other words, they are ordered with the last column first and the first column last. This is evident from the first two elements: [12, 0]. 0 corresponds to the 3 in the first column of `X`, since 3 is the minimum element it was assigned to the first active column. 12 corresponds to the 5 in the second column of `X`. Since the first row occupies 10 distinct columns, the minimum element of the second column (1) gets index 10. The next smallest (3) gets index 11, and the third smallest (5) gets index 12. After sorting, the indices are ordered as we would expect.

Next we look at `active_features_`:

```
ohc.active_features_  # array([  3,  10,  15,  33,  54,  55,  78,  79,  80,  99, 101, 103, 105, 107, 108, 112, 115, 119, 120])
```

Notice that there are 19 elements, which corresponds to the number of distinct elements in our data (one element, 8, was repeated once). Notice also that these are arranged in order. The features that were in the first column of `X` are the same, and the features in the second column have simply been summed with 100, which corresponds to `ohc.feature_indices_[1]`.

Looking back at `out.indices`, we can see that the maximum column number is 18, which is one minus the 19 active features in our encoding. A little thought about the relationship here shows that the indices of `ohc.active_features_` correspond to the column numbers in `ohc.indices`. With this, we can decode:

```
import numpy as np
decode_columns = np.vectorize(lambda col: ohc.active_features_[col])
decoded = decode_columns(out.indices).reshape(X.shape)
```

This gives us:

```
array([[  3, 105],
       [ 10, 101],
       [ 15, 103],
       [ 33, 107],
       [ 54, 108],
       [ 55, 112],
       [ 78, 115],
       [ 79, 119],
       [ 80, 120],
       [ 99, 108]])
```

And we can get back to the original feature values by subtracting off the offsets from `ohc.feature_indices_`:

```
recovered_X = decoded - ohc.feature_indices_[:-1]
array([[ 3,  5],
       [10,  1],
       [15,  3],
       [33,  7],
       [54,  8],
       [55, 12],
       [78, 15],
       [79, 19],
       [80, 20],
       [99,  8]])
```

Note that you will need to have the original shape of `X`, which is simply `(n_samples, n_features)`.

## TL;DR

Given the `sklearn.OneHotEncoder` instance called `ohc`, the encoded data (`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`) output from `ohc.fit_transform` or `ohc.transform` called `out`, and the shape of the original data `(n_samples, n_feature)`, recover the original data `X` with:

```
recovered_X = np.array([ohc.active_features_[col] for col in out.sorted_indices().indices])
                .reshape(n_samples, n_features) - ohc.feature_indices_[:-1]
```

Comment: TBH I skipped to the TL;DR. However, I found it would not work for me unless I used "out.sort_indices().indices" instead of merely "out.indices". Otherwise, I needed to switch the order of my two columns before subtracting "ohc.feature_indices_[:-1]"

Comment: Quite right! I included that in the longer answer but left it out of the TL;DR. I've edited to fix this.

Comment: @Mack Great answer, thank you!  Now, what about when we pass the OneHotEncoded `X` to a predictive model (logistic regression, SVM etc.).  How do we map the model's coefficients back to X?  I want to be able to say, "variable `foo` increases the target by `bar_coeff`" but I don't understand how to map the model's coefficients back to the original category `X`.  Here is the full-blown question posed by another user on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141710/how-to-retrieve-coefficient-names-after-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoding-on-s

Comment: @Mack and here is my question on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041387/how-to-retrieve-original-variables-after-scikit-model-run-w-onehotencoding

Comment: @Phyreese, you can select this as the answer

Comment: @Mack:  I get `AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'sorted_indices'`. Does your answer still work for the latest version of sklearn?

Comment: @Monica, it's been a while since posting this, but I believe that object is a `scipy.csr_matrix`. So you'll want to look at your `scipy` version for compatibility. Alternatively, you can just replace that with code that performs an equivalent sort.

Answer (score 9):

Just compute dot-product of the encoded values with `ohe.active_features_`. It works both for sparse and dense representation. Example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

orig = np.array([6, 9, 8, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 6])

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
encoded = ohe.fit_transform(orig.reshape(-1, 1)) # input needs to be column-wise

decoded = encoded.dot(ohe.active_features_).astype(int)
assert np.allclose(orig, decoded)
```

The key insight is that the `active_features_` attribute of the OHE model represents the original values for each binary column. Thus we can decode the binary-encoded number by simply computing a dot-product with `active_features_`. For each data point there's just a single `1` the position of the original value.

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me when `orig` is a multi-dimensional array (e.g. `orig = np.array([[6, 9, 8, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 6],[6, 9, 8, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 6]])`)

Answer (score 9):

Use [`numpy.argmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) with `axis = 1`.

Example:

```
ohe_encoded = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
ohe_encoded
> array([[0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 0]])

np.argmax(ohe_encoded, axis = 1)
> array([2, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since version 0.20 of scikit-learn, the `active_features_` attribute of the `OneHotEncoder` class has been deprecated, so I suggest to rely on the `categories_` attribute instead.

The below function can help you recover the original data from a matrix that has been one-hot encoded:

```
def reverse_one_hot(X, y, encoder):
    reversed_data = [{} for _ in range(len(y))]
    all_categories = list(itertools.chain(*encoder.categories_))
    category_names = ['category_{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(encoder.categories_))]
    category_lengths = [len(encoder.categories_[i]) for i in range(len(encoder.categories_))]

    for row_index, feature_index in zip(*X.nonzero()):
        category_value = all_categories[feature_index]
        category_name = get_category_name(feature_index, category_names, category_lengths)
        reversed_data[row_index][category_name] = category_value
        reversed_data[row_index]['target'] = y[row_index]

    return reversed_data


def get_category_name(index, names, lengths):

    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(lengths)):
        counter += lengths[i]
        if index < counter:
            return names[i]
    raise ValueError('The index is higher than the number of categorical values')
```

To test it, I have created a small data set that includes the ratings that users have given to users

```
data = [
    {'user_id': 'John', 'item_id': 'The Matrix', 'rating': 5},
    {'user_id': 'John', 'item_id': 'Titanic', 'rating': 1},
    {'user_id': 'John', 'item_id': 'Forrest Gump', 'rating': 2},
    {'user_id': 'John', 'item_id': 'Wall-E', 'rating': 2},
    {'user_id': 'Lucy', 'item_id': 'The Matrix', 'rating': 5},
    {'user_id': 'Lucy', 'item_id': 'Titanic', 'rating': 1},
    {'user_id': 'Lucy', 'item_id': 'Die Hard', 'rating': 5},
    {'user_id': 'Lucy', 'item_id': 'Forrest Gump', 'rating': 2},
    {'user_id': 'Lucy', 'item_id': 'Wall-E', 'rating': 2},
    {'user_id': 'Eric', 'item_id': 'The Matrix', 'rating': 2},
    {'user_id': 'Eric', 'item_id': 'Die Hard', 'rating': 3},
    {'user_id': 'Eric', 'item_id': 'Forrest Gump', 'rating': 5},
    {'user_id': 'Eric', 'item_id': 'Wall-E', 'rating': 4},
    {'user_id': 'Diane', 'item_id': 'The Matrix', 'rating': 4},
    {'user_id': 'Diane', 'item_id': 'Titanic', 'rating': 3},
    {'user_id': 'Diane', 'item_id': 'Die Hard', 'rating': 5},
    {'user_id': 'Diane', 'item_id': 'Forrest Gump', 'rating': 3},
]

data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data)
data_frame = data_frame[['user_id', 'item_id', 'rating']]
ratings = data_frame['rating']
data_frame.drop(columns=['rating'], inplace=True)
```

If we are building a prediction model, we have to remember to delete the dependent variable (in this case the rating) from the `DataFrame` before we encode it.

```
ratings = data_frame['rating']
data_frame.drop(columns=['rating'], inplace=True)
```

Then we proceed to do the encoding

```
ohc = OneHotEncoder()
encoded_data = ohc.fit_transform(data_frame)
print(encoded_data)
```

Which results in:

```
  (0, 2)    1.0
  (0, 6)    1.0
  (1, 2)    1.0
  (1, 7)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (2, 5)    1.0
  (3, 2)    1.0
  (3, 8)    1.0
  (4, 3)    1.0
  (4, 6)    1.0
  (5, 3)    1.0
  (5, 7)    1.0
  (6, 3)    1.0
  (6, 4)    1.0
  (7, 3)    1.0
  (7, 5)    1.0
  (8, 3)    1.0
  (8, 8)    1.0
  (9, 1)    1.0
  (9, 6)    1.0
  (10, 1)   1.0
  (10, 4)   1.0
  (11, 1)   1.0
  (11, 5)   1.0
  (12, 1)   1.0
  (12, 8)   1.0
  (13, 0)   1.0
  (13, 6)   1.0
  (14, 0)   1.0
  (14, 7)   1.0
  (15, 0)   1.0
  (15, 4)   1.0
  (16, 0)   1.0
  (16, 5)   1.0
```

After encoding the we can reverse using the `reverse_one_hot` function we defined above, like this:

```
reverse_data = reverse_one_hot(encoded_data, ratings, ohc)
print(pandas.DataFrame(reverse_data))
```

Which gives us:

```
   category_1    category_2  target
0        John    The Matrix       5
1        John       Titanic       1
2        John  Forrest Gump       2
3        John        Wall-E       2
4        Lucy    The Matrix       5
5        Lucy       Titanic       1
6        Lucy      Die Hard       5
7        Lucy  Forrest Gump       2
8        Lucy        Wall-E       2
9        Eric    The Matrix       2
10       Eric      Die Hard       3
11       Eric  Forrest Gump       5
12       Eric        Wall-E       4
13      Diane    The Matrix       4
14      Diane       Titanic       3
15      Diane      Die Hard       5
16      Diane  Forrest Gump       3
```

Comment: what library did you get `matrix_utils` from?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck It's a personal library. I have fixed the code now.

Answer (score 1):

If the features are dense, like [1,2,4,5,6], with several number missed. Then, we can mapping them to corresponding positions.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> def _sparse_binary(y):
...     # one-hot codes of y with scipy.sparse matrix.
...     row = np.arange(len(y))
...     col = y - y.min()
...     data = np.ones(len(y))
...     return sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))
... 
>>> y = np.random.randint(-2,2, 8).reshape([4,2])
>>> y
array([[ 0, -2],
       [-2,  1],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 0, -2]])
>>> yc = [_sparse_binary(y[:,i]) for i in xrange(2)]
>>> for i in yc: print i.todense()
... 
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]]
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]
>>> [i.shape for i in yc]
[(4, 4), (4, 4)]
```

This is a compromised and simple method, but works and easy to reverse by argmax(), e.g.:

```
>>> np.argmax(yc[0].todense(), 1) + y.min(0)[0]
matrix([[ 0],
        [-2],
        [ 1],
        [ 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to one-hot encode

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42874726/562769

```
import numpy as np
nb_classes = 6
data = [[2, 3, 4, 0]]

def indices_to_one_hot(data, nb_classes):
    """Convert an iterable of indices to one-hot encoded labels."""
    targets = np.array(data).reshape(-1)
    return np.eye(nb_classes)[targets]
```

### How to reverse

```
def one_hot_to_indices(data):
    indices = []
    for el in data:
        indices.append(list(el).index(1))
    return indices


hot = indices_to_one_hot(orig_data, nb_classes)
indices = one_hot_to_indices(hot)

print(orig_data)
print(indices)
```

gives:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 0]]
[2, 3, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no". The encoder takes your categorical data and automagically transforms it to a reasonable set of numbers.

The longer answer is "not automatically". If you provide an explicit mapping using the n_values parameter, though, you can probably implement own decoding at the other side. See the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) for some hints on how that might be done.

That said, this is a fairly strange question. You may want to, instead, use a [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer)

Comment: I feel like I have the same lack of understanding. Why is this a strange question? Without decoding I wouldn't be able to tell what factor coded into 0,1 is paired with what coefficient

Comment: the onehotencoding implements the vanilla one-of-k algorithm - which optimizes performance by not using a fixed ordering for parameters. this means the algorithm doesn't guarantee the same encoding on multiple runs, and is not reversible. i'm not sure of your use case - if you're looking to do decoding, you're most likely using the wrong algorithm implementation - look at DictVectorizer, or extend the default with a mapping and a custom decoder.

Comment: While it is true that the algorithm does not guarantee the same encoding on multiple runs, it is false that it is not reversible. It is actually quite easily reversible. Please see my answer for the procedure and a thorough explanation.

Comment: @Mack have you read your answer and explanation? we have different definitions of easy i think ;)

Comment: I suppose we do. The TL;DR isn't so bad though. : )

Comment: For me I tried to use the dictvectorizer, but my pandas dataframe was too big to convert to a dict of dicts. Hence Mack's answer provided me some of the functionality I needed.

Comment: @blueberryfields Now *I'm* confused. If I run `onehot.fit()`, can I then safely run `onehot.transform()` on different input matrices and get resulting matrices with the same meaning?

Answer (score -1):

Pandas approach : 
To convert categorical variables to binary variables, `pd.get_dummies`  does that and to convert them back, you can find the index of the value where there is 1 using `pd.Series.idxmax()`. Then you can map to a list(index in according to original data) or dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col = np.random.randint(1,5,20)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': col})
df.head()

    A
0   2
1   2
2   1
3   1
4   3

df_dum = pd.get_dummies(df['A'])
df_dum.head()

    1   2   3   4
0   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   0   0
3   1   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   0


df_n = df_dum.apply(lambda x: x.idxmax(), axis = 1)
df_n.head()

0    2
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    3
```

Comment: This is not an answer to this question!