# How to Retrieve Original Variables After Scikit Model Run w/OneHotEncoding

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have successfully ran a logistic regression model from the scikit-learn [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) package but cannot easily interpret the model's coefficients (accessed via `SGDClassifier.coef_`) because the input data was transformed via scikit-learn's [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

My original input data `X` is of shape (12000,11):

```
X = np.array([[1,4,3...9,4,1],
              [5,9,2...3,1,4],
              ...
              [7,8,1...6,7,8]
              ])
```

I then applied one hot encoding:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder()
X_OHE = enc.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

which produces an array of shape (12000, 696):

```
X_OHE = np.array([[1,0,1...0,0,1],
                 [0,0,0...0,1,0],
                  ...
                 [1,0,1...0,0,1]
                 ])
```

I then access the model's coefficients with `SGDClassifier.coef_` which produces an array of shape (1,696):

```
coefs = np.array([[-1.233e+00,0.9123e+00,-2.431e+00...-0.238e+01,-1.33e+00,0.001e-01]])
```

How do I map the coefficient values back to the original values in `X`, so I can say something like, "if variable `foo` has a value of `bar`, the target variable increases/decreases by `bar_coeff`"?

Let me know if you need more info on the data or the model parameters.  Thank you.

I found one unanswered question about this on SO: [How to retrieve coefficient names after label encoding and one hot encoding on scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141710/how-to-retrieve-coefficient-names-after-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoding-on-s)

Comment: Lets say a single feature in original data is converted into 4 features in one-hot encoded data. All these 4 features will have different coefficients, how do you plan to combine these into original feature?

Comment: I think you've just asked the same question that I posted above.

Comment: Yes, thats what I was trying to say. Its not available in the library because its not a fixed way to interpret the results. The other question you linked says that it was asked on Cross-validated, but referred here. I would advise you to again ask this on Cross-validated, but not with the current question form. Rather remove the libraries and programming and just describe about what you want to do, and what may be the best practices to do so. If and when you get any satisfactory way to interpret the one-hot encoded coeffs, try programming it. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll post on Cross Validate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing this user's detailed explanation of `OneHotEncoder` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35898452/4245462), I was able to create a (somewhat hack-y) approach to relating model coefficients back to the original data set.

Assuming you've correctly setup your `OneHotEncoder`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from scipy import sparse

enc = OneHotEncoder()
X_OHE = enc.fit_transform(X)   # X and X_OHE as described in question
```

And you have successfully ran a GLM model, say:

```
from sklearn import linear_model

clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Which has coefficients `clf.coef_`:

```
print clf.coef_
# np.array([[-1.233e+00,0.9123e+00,-2.431e+00...-0.238e+01,-1.33e+00,0.001e-01]])
```

You can use the below approach to trace the encoded 1's and 0's in `X_OHE` back to the original values in `X`.  I'd recommend reading the mentioned detailed explanation on `OneHotEncoding` (link at top), else the below will seem like gibberish.  But in a nutshell, the below iterates over each `feature` in `X_OHE` and uses the `feature_indices` parameter internal to `enc` to make the translation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
results = []

for i in range(enc.active_features_.shape[0]):
    f = enc.active_features_[i]

    index_range = np.extract(enc.feature_indices_ <= f, enc.feature_indices_)
    s = len(index_range) - 1
    f_index = index_range[-1]
    f_label_decoded = f - f_index

    results.append({
            'label_decoded_value': f_label_decoded,
            'coefficient': clf.coef_[0][i]
        })

R = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
```

Where R looks like this (I original encoded the names of company departments):

```
coefficient label_decoded_value
3.929413    DepartmentFoo1
3.718078    DepartmentFoo2
3.101869    DepartmentFoo3
2.892845    DepartmentFoo4
...
```

So, now you can say, "The target variables increases by 3.929413 when an employee is in department 'Foo1'.

Comment: thanks, @NickBraunagel, and did you adapt it for the case when you have encoded **multiple categorical variables** ?

Comment: @BrigitteCharpent - it’s been a while since writing the above code but I believe it will handle anything that’s you’ve encoded as it’s looping over the active features via `enc.active_features_[i]`.