# Create a single categorical variable based on many dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several category dummies that are mutually exclusive

```
id  cat1 cat2 cat3
A    0    0    1
B    1    0    0
C    1    0    0
D    0    0    1
E    0    1    0
F    0    0    1
..
```

I want to create a new column that contains all categories

```
id  cat1 cat2 cat3 type
A    0    0    1   cat3
B    1    0    0   cat1
C    1    0    0   cat1
D    0    0    1   cat3
E    0    1    0   cat2
F    0    0    1   cat3
..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the columns starting with "cat":

```
df['type'] = pd.from_dummies(df.filter(like='cat'))
```

Output:

```
  id  cat1  cat2  cat3  type
0  A     0     0     1  cat3
1  B     1     0     0  cat1
2  C     1     0     0  cat1
3  D     0     0     1  cat3
4  E     0     1     0  cat2
5  F     0     0     1  cat3
```

Comment: This is great - I never used this before, had been using the sklearn [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and variations of [its inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548731/how-to-reverse-sklearn-onehotencoder-transform-to-recover-original-data) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for column with `cat` substring, if multiple `1` per rows are separated by `,`:

```
m = df.filter(like='cat').eq(1)
#all columns without first
#m = df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(1)
df['type'] = m.dot(m.columns + ',').str[:-1]
print (df)
  id  cat1  cat2  cat3  type
0  A     0     0     1  cat3
1  B     1     0     0  cat1
2  C     1     0     0  cat1
3  D     0     0     1  cat3
4  E     0     1     0  cat2
5  F     0     0     1  cat3
```